# How to set cookie expiry/max-age as 30 days in flutter web

Tags: flutter, windows, google-chrome, ubuntu, cookies

I have created a cookie(max-age was set as 30days in seconds) in my localhost, When I have deployed the flutter web app in chrome(Ubuntu latest browser v117.0.5938.88 stable release), cookie max-age was set correct but When I deployed the same web app in chrome (windows OS, latest browser v117.0.5938.89 stable) the cookie max-age was set as 7 days (approx)

I have expiry attribute for 30days as some browser use expiry instead of max-age, but it wasn't working.I have used dart:html library for creating of cookie

```
 html.document.cookie = '$AUTH_COOKIE_ADMIN_WEB_TOKEN_KEY=$cookie_value; path=/; max-age=${DateUtility.THIRTY_DAYS_IN_SECONDS}; expiry=${DateTime.now().add(Duration(days: 30)).toUtc().toIso8601String()}';.
```

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.